# BehavioursSubject value updated unexpectedly

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

```
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core"; import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject";

@Injectable() export class ClinicalFilteringService implements OnDestroy {
    private filtersSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
    filters = this.filtersSource.asObservable();

    private savedSearchesSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
    savedSearches = this.savedSearchesSource.asObservable();

    setFilters(name, filter){
        let currentFilter = this.filtersSource.getValue();
        currentFilter[name] = filter;
        if(currentFilter[name].length === 0){
            delete currentFilter[name];
        }
        this.filtersSource.next(currentFilter);
    }

    saveSearches(filters, name){
        let currentSavedSearches = this.savedSearchesSource.getValue();
        currentSavedSearches[name] = filters;
        this.savedSearchesSource.next(currentSavedSearches);
    }

}
```

I'm new to angular, I'm having trouble with BehaviourSubject. So I have 2 BehavioralSubject which are `filtersSource` and `savedSearchesSource`. `savedSearchesSource`will be updated on click event and `filtersSource` will be updated on filtering event on a chart. The problem is everytime I call setFilters `setFilters` to update `filtersSource` it will also update `this.savedSearchesSource.getValue()` value. I'm not sure why its happening.

Here's the component that using the service

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, ChangeDetectorRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Auth } from '../../../services/auth-service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { Params, ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { SearchBarService } from '../../../services/search-bar-service';
import { GenericAutocompleteResult } from '../../../model/autocomplete-result';
import { MatSnackBar, MatSnackBarRef } from '@angular/material';
import { SnackbarDemoComponent } from '../../parts/snackbar-demo/snackbar-demo.component';
import { ClinicalFilteringService } from '../../../services/clinical-filtering.service';
import { HelperService } from '../../../services/helper.service';

const SMALL_WIDTH = 720;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-search',
    templateUrl: './search.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./search.component.css'],
    providers: [SearchBarService]
})
export class SearchComponent implements  OnInit {
    subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
    sbSub: Subscription = null;
    autocomplete: GenericAutocompleteResult<any>;
    error = '';
    searching = false;
    sb: MatSnackBarRef<SnackbarDemoComponent> = null;
    filters = {};
    objectKeys= Object.keys;
    private mediaMatcher: MediaQueryList = matchMedia(`(max-width: ${SMALL_WIDTH}px)`);

    constructor(public searchBarService: SearchBarService,
                public auth: Auth,
                private route: ActivatedRoute,
                private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
                public snackBar: MatSnackBar,
                private router: Router,
                private clinicalFilteringService: ClinicalFilteringService,
                private helper: HelperService,
            ) {
        if (auth.authenticated()) {
            this.subscriptions.push(route.params.subscribe(p => this.parseParams(p)));
        }
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.clinicalFilteringService.filters.subscribe(filter => this.filters = filter)
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscriptions.forEach((s => s.unsubscribe()));
    }

    handleError(e: string) {
        this.error = e;
    }


    deleteFilter(name: string){
        return this.clinicalFilteringService.deleteFilter(name);
    }

    saveSearches(name){
        return this.clinicalFilteringService.saveSearches(name);
    }
}
```

it keeps changing the `this.filters` where it used as parameter for the function of the service. Any help on how to solve this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: Component code please

Comment: Welcome to SO, remember when posting a question, include all relevant code. Imagine us trying your code for example in a stackblitz, the code you are presenting is not enought to test your code :)

Comment: You're constantly re-emitting the same object, that you mutate before re-emitting it. If you store the same object in two arrays, and then mutate this single object, then the two arrays contain the same, modified object. Same here. Also, please, use types. Stop using any for everything.

Comment: in the `saveSearches(filters, name)` you are passing the same variable name which you defined as observable thats why it is conflicting, change it something else

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, I guess that's the problem. can you help me with a solution regarding this problem?

Comment: @Exterminator it doesn't work either. I don't think filters inside the parameters of saveSearches have anything to do with observable variable I created.

Comment: Well, just don't do that. Create a new object and emit it when calling setFilters() instead of mutating the current object.

Comment: either change filters `saveSearches()` every place or change the observable name.

Comment: and in savesearchs function in component you are passing one variable and at the receiving end you are getting two

Comment: @JBNizet Hey thanks a lot!! I just used Object.assign to create a copy of the value, and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to JBNizet. I found the problem is because I constantly re-emitting the same object, that I mutate before re-emitting it. My solution is to create a new object that hold the value to be used for .next().